# SwiftUI Are Presentation Detents supported on iPad?

Tags: ipad, swiftui, swiftui-sheet

So I have a minimum target of iOS 16, am using .sheet() with .presentationDetents([.medium]) and it works fine on iOS (iPhone). But when I load it on iPadOS it's always a fullsized sheet, seemingly ignoring the presentation detents. Here is a minimal reproducable code that demonstrates this behaviour.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shouldShowSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                shouldShowSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldShowSheet, content: {
            VStack {
                Text("Some content")
                Text("Some more content")
                Text("Even more content")
                
                Button("Dismiss Sheet") {
                    shouldShowSheet.toggle()
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Below are screenshots of the same code running on iOS and running on iPadOS
[image]

[image]

I tried using .fraction, .medium, .height and none of them had any effect on iPad sheets. The sheet is always a full-sized one as shown in the image. But on iOS(iPhone) it works as expected.

I'm expecting sheets on iPads to also respect the presentation detents. How can I get different sized sheets on iPad?

Comment: This might be a SwiftUI bug because presentation detents do work on iPad in UIKit.

Comment: This isn't a bug. This is showing as expected. If you are in a smaller SplitView, I believe it works as on iPhone.

Comment: So it's expected to be a fullsize sheet if it's size class .regular, and still show as a presentation detents respecting sheet when it's .compact for example if splitview? I tried looking for documentation stating this but could not seem to find it.

And if so, what can I do to have sheet behaviour on .compact, and have a smaller alternative similar to sheet style of presentation on the iPad when it's size class .regular?

Comment: @Yrb is there anything in the documentation to support this?

Comment: Where you ever able to figure out how to control the .sheet size on iPad? .presentationDetents is not working for me either.